# Assertion failed in opencv rgbd.warpFrame in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to use to use the function warpframe as defined here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d3a/group__rgbd.html#gac0db6aeba01fa17ec2c69694497926f0

When executing the function I fail the following assertion

> matrix_wrap.cpp:1393: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function 'cv::_OutputArray::create'

As far as I understand it fails a check when creating the output arrays?

I call the function as follows

```
warpedImage, warpedDepth, warpedMask = cv2.rgbd.warpFrame(image, depth, mask, Rt, cameraMatrix, distCoeff)
```

With the following paramters:

> ```
> image has a shape: (800, 1200, 3) and contains numpy.uint8
> depth has a shape: (800, 1200) and contains numpy.float64
> mask has a shape: (800, 1200) and contains numpy.uint8
> rt has a shape: (3, 4) and contains numpy.float64
> cameraMatrix has a shape: (3, 3) and contains numpy.float64
> distCoeff has a shape: (5,) and contains numpy.float64
> ```

I also tried with giving the output arrays as parameters, with them being numpy arrays of the same shape as the image,depth and mask. But that gave the same error.

My package versions are the following:

```
numpy                 1.22.2 
opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.62
opencv-python         4.5.5.62
python                3.10.2
```

I don't understand the assertion i'm failing. Which type is wrong and what should it be?
If somebody knows what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the error message is not so descriptive.

The problem is arriving due to the shape of your transformation matrix, i.e., `Rt`. **The transformation matrix should be either 3x3 or 4x4 in shape.** Kindly append a row having [0, 0, 0, 1] to `Rt`. A sample transformation matrix is shown below:

```
Rt = numpy.array(
    [
        [ 0.8137977, -0.4698463,  0.3420202, 0.1903262],
        [ 0.5438381,  0.8231729, -0.1631759, 0.4057564],
        [-0.2048741,  0.3187958,  0.9254166, 0.2690871], 
        [       0.0,        0.0,        0.0,       1.0],
    ]
)
```